# Framer motion library bug when using with reagent

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent, framer-motion

I'm using the framer-motion library to animate a div mount

This is what I have:

```
(:require [framer-motion :refer (motion MagicMotion AnimateSharedLayout AnimatePresence useSpring useMotionValue useTransform useViewportScroll) :as motion])
(def div (.-div motion))
(defn my-component []
    [:> div {
      :initial {:opacity 0}
      :animate {:opacity 1}
      :exit {:opacity 0}} 
"Show Me"])
```

And a boolean show-my-component? is changed from false to true when I click on a button (I'm using re-frame for managing the boolean show-my-component? but have simplified the code here):

```
[:button {:on-click (change-show-my-component-boolean-to-true)}]
(if show-my-component? [my-component])
```

But the component doesn't show immediately when clicking the button when using :>div, although it does when using a regular :div, but in the latter case of course there's no animation

when using :> div, I have to re-focus or click somewhere on the webpage for my-component to show

-- EDIT --

The opacity animation from 0 to 1 is triggered on click, and not on page load. The component isn't being focused the first time. It focuses when the window is refocused and thus the animation triggers.
Reagent isn't focusing the framer motion motion.div object automatically on page load. In the same situation react would.

Framer Motion states:

https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#mount-animations
"
Mount animations

When a component mounts, it'll automatically animate to the values in animate if they're different from those defined in style or initial. You can set the initial prop to false to use the value in animate as the component's mounted state to disable mount animations.

<motion.div animate={{ x: 100 }} initial={false} />
This will also work with server-side rendering."

The component is mounted:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center border-5" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
```

And has opacity 0. The mounted div is stuck at :initial.

-- EDIT --

The animation isn't triggered when a click is simulated by adding these to the :> div map:

```
{:ref simulate-click
         :on-click #(prn "element clicked!")}
```

where simulate-click is:

```
(defn simulate-click [e]
  (prn "event is " e)
  (-> e .click)
  )
```